# Link error in c++ & DirectX file include problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx

I have two header files:

**DirectX_Engine.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Main.h"
#include <d3d9.h>
```

and:

**Main.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include "DirectX_Engine.h"

int imRunning = 1;
```

After compiling, I get the following linker errors:

```
error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
error LNK2005: "int imRunning" (?imRunning@@3HA) already defined in DirectX_Engine.obj
```

I'm also getting a 'file is not found or directory doesn't exist error' when `#include`ing "d3dx9.h". Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas. Firstly, you are including `DirectX_Engine.h` in `Main.h` and `Main.h` in `DirectX_Engine.h`. This will obviously not work.

Secondly, `int imRunning` gets included to each .cpp file that includes `Main.h` and the compiler treats it as a definition. Then the linker comes and sees `imRunning` defined in each of these files and doesn't know what to do. The solution is using extern:

In `Main.h`:

```
extern int imRunning;
```

In **one of** the .cpp files:

```
int imRunning = 1;
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much. :) Oh, do you have any idea about the DirectX file missing?

Comment: Do you have DirectX SDK installed? If so, check that the DX SDK include and lib directories are added to search paths.

Answer (score 0):

d3dx9.h doesn't come with VS or Platform SDK.  You'll need to go back to MSDN downloads and get DirectX SDK.